# Система отзывов с оценкой

Tags: python, django

Всем привет!) Относительно недавно начал изучать фреймворк Django и в качестве проекта захотел написать полноценный сайт отзывов. Столкнулся с одной проблемой, что сделал модели самого Поста (в котором описывают, например, фирму и т.д.) + Отзывы к этому посту + Категории услуг, но не получается вывести среднюю оценку каждого поста исходя из оценок отзывов. Уже 3 дня сижу и не могу понять как сделать адекватную функцию по выводу средней оценки каждого поста. Models.py у меня выглядит так:

```
DEFAULT_CHOICES = (
    ('5', 'Отлично'),
    ('4', 'Хорошо'),
    ('3', 'Нормально'),
    ('2', 'Плохо'),
    ('1', 'Ужасно'),
)

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)   # заголовок статьи 
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')   # формирования URL-ов в виде букв и цифр для улучшения распознавания поисковой системой
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/posts_images/', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')   # автор публикации
    body = models.TextField()   # сама статья 
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)   # время когда опубликовано
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   # время создания
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)   # время редактирования  
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')  # статус блога (например "опубликовано")
    average_rating = models.FloatField(verbose_name=('Average rating'), default=0,)
    objects = models.Manager()  # Менеджер по умолчанию
    published = PublishedManager()  # Новый менеджер
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)  # сортировка статей по дате публикация (по убыванию)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])

    def get_averages(self, max_value=None):
        max_rating_value = 0
        post_maximums = {}
        post_averages = {}
        posts = Post.objects.filter(counts_for_average=True, value__comment=self)
        # Высчитываем среднее значение каждого поста
        for post in posts:
            post_average = None
            ratings = Comment.objects.filter(comment=self, post=post, value__isnull=False).exclude(value='')
            post_max = post_maximums[post]
            for comment in comments:
                if post_average is None:
                    post_average = float(comment.value)
                else:
                    post_average += float(comment.value)

            if post_average is not None:
                post_average *= float(max_rating_value) / float(post_max)
                post_averages[post] = (post_average / ratings.count())

        total_average = 0
        for post, post_average in post_averages.posts():
            total_average += post_average
        if not len(post_averages):
            return (False, False)
        total_average /= len(post_averages)

        return total_average, post_averages

    def get_average_rating(self, max_value=None):
        total_average, post_averages = self.get_averages(max_value=max_value)
        return total_average

    def get_post_averages(self, max_value=None):
        total_average, post_averages = self.get_averages(max_value=max_value)
        return post_averages



class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('created', 'Created'),
        ('active', 'Active'),
    )
    rating_choices = DEFAULT_CHOICES
    value = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, 
        verbose_name=('Value'), 
        choices=rating_choices,
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')  # делаем отношение "один ко многим", что бы в статье можно было оставлять несколько комментариев
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='comments/images/', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='active')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # Добавляем булевое поле, что бы можно было скрывать определенные комментарии
    commented = CommentedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.value, self.post)
```

**P.S. Сидел до ночи и все таки удалось решить эту задачу с помощью Numpy. Заняло это 3 строки, кому интересно:**

```
def average_rating(self):
    all_ratings = list(map(lambda x: x.value, self.comments.all()))
    average = np.array(all_ratings).astype(np.float)
    return np.average(average)
```

Так что теперь в админке у меня наконец то выводится средняя оценка Поста исходя из всех отзывов. Единственное что, пока не знаю как эту оценку потом вывести на главную страницу возле каждого поста))
И вообще интересно, как Вы оцениваете данное решение? Слишком ли я все сделал через жопу или все таки такой вариант имеет место быть? Всем заранее и по факту спасибо!)

Comment: обычно модели данных и логику принято разделять

Comment: Спасибо за наблюдение, знаю это) Просто я гуглил как выводить среднюю оценку поста по всем отзывам в нем и нашел вариант на GitHub, там было это в моделях написан часть этого кода с логикой, я под свои модели переделал и так и оставил, поскольку не знал куда это правильно будет всунуть.

Comment: могу скинуть как делал похожее у себя

Comment: Вадим, буду очень благодарен за помощь) Сюда сможешь скинуть? Или какой то контакт дать для этого?)

Answer (score 0):

Самый производительный способ это создать новую модель, где будет сохранено количество отызвов в бд и сумма всех оценок. Т.е. при сохранении отзыва сумма всех оценок увеличивается на значение этой оценки, а количество записей на 1. Когда нужно вывести среднюю оценку нужно сумму всех оценок разделить на количество, это и будет среднее значение

Есть более просто способ, но менее производительный. Так же его можно использовать, если в бд уже есть записи, а таблица не была создана. Если интересен второй вариант, то напишите комментарий

Upd 2 способ:

```
# Пример функции, которая может быть использована для подсчёте
def calculate_average_rating():
    # Сумма оценок
    sum_of_raiting = 0
    # Количество оценок
    count = 0
    # Находим все оценки от 1 до 5
    for raiting in range(6):
        # Получаем объекты оценок
        objs = Comment.objects.filter(rating_choices=raiting)
        # складываем кол-во оценок
        count += objs.count()
        # складываем сумму оценок
        sum_of_raiting += objs.count() * i
    # возвращаем среднюю оценку или None, если не удалось посчитать оценку
    if count > 0:
        return sum_of_raiting / count
    else:
        return None
```

P.S. У вас ошибка в models.py.
Должно быть:

```
rating_choices = models.IntegerField(choices=DEFAULT_CHOICES)
```

Comment: На данном этапе интересен любой из вариантов, по этому очень бы хотелось ознакомиться со вторым вариантом :)
Буду очень признателен за помощь!)

P.S. если для Вас это не накладно, то буду очень рад ознакомиться с двумя вариантами))

Comment: @atom1k добавил второй способ

Comment: @lnventor Попробовал, поменял правда в твоей функции немного переменные, потому что у меня не raiting, a value (на всякий случай пробовал и чисто твой вариант копипастить), но не работает, в админке изменений в средней оценке поста не произошло. Мне этот код же нужно было в модели добавить, верно? Может в моей модели Post не хватает переменной которая будет ссылаться на Comment.value и соответственно оценка будет прикреплятся конкретно от каждого отзыва к посту? Ибо мне просто моя интуиция подсказывает что Value (то есть рейтинг 1-5) не заносится конкретно в Post, а заносится только в Comment

Comment: @atom1k первый способ должен быть в models и привязываться к сигналу post_save, второй способ может быть где угодно, лучше если ты вынесешь такие функции (бизнес логику) в отдельный файл. Но ты должен импортировать это во views и вызывать эту функцию, она тебе вернёт среднюю оценку, а дальше с этой информацией можешь делать что угодно